# Alternatives to LAMP for an webapplication

Tags: web-services, web, lamp

I'm looking for a good alternative to the classic LAMP. On the one hand, I don't like PHP, and on the other hand I'm not sure if it fits that well.

Roughly speaking, the project is about uploading an XML-File, parsing it, and then displaying it.

The traffic won't be that high, though it has to be pretty stable.

There are some alternatives I am familiar with:

1. Python: Yeah, I'm worked on my last project with it and I liked it. But I don't have a decent IDE (Coding in Notepad++ and uploading it via ftp and THEN starting it via shell. I don't really like vim or such editors on Unix).
2. Java: I have learned Java for 3 years in vocational college, but Java isn't my favorite. (Maybe it's because of my teacher. An ofc Java isn't fast but pretty stable and secure.
3. C++: I have never really worked with it, but I attended lectures of C++ in university. Still, I'm not very familiar with C++.
4. Perl: Would be an option but... I HATE IT and I'm also not really familiar
5. Node.js: Would be interesting but I have no real clue about Coding in node.js and I'm not sure if it fits my requirements

I'm always interested in learning something new :) So if you have any suggestions, feel free to tell me.

Comment: I have never worked with it yet

Comment: .NET has built in controls to upload files... And really nice namespaces to parse xml documents.

Comment: But does .NET only work on ms servers? It is very likekly that I have to develop on a linux server.

Comment: Thought it worth noting for those who might stumble upon this question via search, etc. that .NET has become much more Linux friendly.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution could be a MEAN stack.

This stands for MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, and Node.js. Althought, this would be more ideal for JSON type files, not XML